# Why not always use ::operator new instead of new (without even constructing)?

Tags: c++

I've been trying this code, where Vector3 has 3 members x, y, z. In Vector3, I made copies, copies with move etc.

```
    Vector3* data = (Vector3*)::operator new(2 * sizeof(Vector3));

    //new (&data[0]) Vector3(1., 2., 3.);
    //new (&data[1]) Vector3(2., 4., 5.);

    data[0] = Vector3(1., 2., 3.);
    data[1] = Vector3(2., 4., 5.);

    std::cout << data[0].x << " " << data[0].y << " " << data[0].z << '\n';
    std::cout << data[1].x << " " << data[1].y << " " << data[1].z << '\n';

    data[0].~Vector3();
    data[1].~Vector3();

    ::operator delete(data, 2 * sizeof(Vector3));
```

In the first line, I only allocate the memory. The following commented 2 lines is how I was told I should construct the vectors with the placement new, so that the class is constructed and emplaced there.
However, if I write the next 2 lines instead, without any specific construction of the class at each index, it still seems to work. What is the catch? Is it not supposed to work? Will it break at some point? Are there things that are not copied correctly?

Because, if it works, what is even the point of constructing the classes with the new/new[] operator, which take more time because of the construction of the classes?

Comment: Whether this code is correct or not depends on the details of the `Vector3` class. With the placement new lines included it is correct irrespective of the details of `Vector3`. So the version with placement new should be preferred.

Comment: Important rule of C++, don't expect bad code to always cause an error. Try to protect yourself by following the rules of C++, not by 'seeing what works' because one day it won't.

Comment: As for the question about time, don't forget if the constructor really does nothing the compiler will optimise away the call to the constructor.

Comment: Your question seems to boil down to "why have constructors?"

Comment: **Don't optimize prematurely** Prefer code that is easier to read and maintain. While above code might works fine in a simple function, it real application, it can be hard to ensure that you don't have leak, that your code is exception safe and that object are destroyed the appropriate way. Many compilers will optimize the code and a proifiler should be used if you have a performance problem. **Be sure to optimize at the proper level**. Selecting appropriate algorithm and containers might have more impact of performance that micro-optimisation,

Comment: And if you want to write code by hand, you could just go with C instead of C++.

Comment: Your code has potential **undefined behavior**. If `Vector3` is a class that allocated memory, you would clearly have problems when assigning to it as you would try to destroy old value that is not properly initialized. 

That can make the code very fragile as a change to `Vector3` class can cause the code to break. In production application, one want to avoid any code that is potentially dangerous.

Also be aware that current compiler sometime assume that a program do not have undefined behavior and if it not the case, generated code might be incorrect. That can lead to hard to find bugs.

Answer (score 2):

When writing

```
data[0] = Vector3(1., 2., 3.);
```

the assignment operator is used, and it supposes that the left-hand-side (`data[0]`) already exists and is already initialised in order to modify it according to the right-hand-side.
But it is not, here, because you just allocated the storage.

In this simple case with a structure made of plain-old-data this won't harm, but if your structure contained members that manage resources (file descriptor, memory...) then an attempt to release the undefined resources of the left-hand-side would be dramatic.

You should not do this, and as stated in the comments of the question, you won't gain anything doing so.

As stated in the comments below, a compiler should even decide not do anything related to the written code since the object which is concerned by the operation is not even supposed to exist.

Comment: It is more than just initialization; there is also the abstract machine concept of "object actually exists there".

Answer (score 2):

C++ doesn't specify how it works on the hardware you compile to.  C++ specifies how it works on an abstract machine.  That abstract machine has properties that are "non-physical", in that they are unlikely to be actually in existence on the machine you physically compile to.

One example of a non-physical property of the abstract machine is that it actually keeps track of what objects exists and where they are.  And if you attempt to interact with an object that doesn't exist or is of the wrong type (outside of some specific exceptions), the C++ standard no longer specifies what behaviour the abstract machine should have.  For the entire program execution, not just in the set of instructions where you interact with the non-existent object as if it exists.

C++ compilers, in theory, translate your C++ code into behaviour on that abstract machine, then translate that into assembly instructions.  But that translation -- from abstract machine to assembly -- is permitted to do **anything at all** if the rules of the abstract machine are violated.  This most often occurs in optimization, where instead of naively mapping operations from C++ to the target hardware, things are reordered and assumptions made about what is and is not legal.

A common example of this kind of optimization is aliasing.  In C++ if a function takes a `double*` and a `int const*` and a length, then iterates over the `int const*` convering them to `double`s and writing it out, it is **not legal** for the two buffers to overlap.

Because either an `int` lives at each memory address or a `double`, not both, **period**.

In turn, this means that the compiler can load a batch of ints, convert them in a batch to doubles, then write that batch out.  Without the no-aliasing requirement, each read would have to be done with a write before doing another read, because the earlier writes might overwrite the later int reads!

The C++ compiler treat object identity as more than just some bytes interpreted in some specific way.  And the ability for the compiler to understand when an object is read or written to is key for it to sensibly be able to transform C++ code into more optimal assembly than the completely paranoid unoptimized version might require.

There are only a few ways to create an object in C++.  A new expression (placement or not), declaring a variable, engaging a union in just the right way, and (in newer standard version) certain operation involving treating raw memory as primitive types (which arguably, as the object comes into existence retroactively in some readings, include time travel).

But really, if you are playing with raw uninitialized memory you want to put objects into, just use placement new.  It is the very least you can do.